# How to style registration form in django using bootstrap

Tags: django

So I have set up a user registration portal for my website. It is in form of plain HTML text. I have downloaded a bootstrap file for registration portal but it simply does not work.

```
from django import forms
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        label='User Name',
    )
    name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        label='Full Name',
    )
    last = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        label='Last Name',
    ),

    email = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        label='Email',
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )
```

Below is my bootstrap. Can you tell me the error here. It simply does not work

```
<form method="POST" class="signup">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
  <div class="loginBox">
    <img src="user.png" class="user">
    <h2>Resgister Here</h2>
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=""> {{ form.email }}
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder=""> {{ form.username }}
    <p>Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=""> {{ form.name }}
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="••••••"> {{ form.password }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="register">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It helps to be more specific than "it simply does not work". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: You are using a dual form in the templates 1){{ form.as_p }} and another showing individual  form fields, please remove one,

Comment: i want to remove user registration form from forms.py ... and want to take output from register.html.... then what should i write in form.py so that it goes to my views.py

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see is an unnecessry comma at the end of the field `last`.

```
last = forms.CharField(
    required=True,
    max_length=30,
    label='Last Name',
),
```

Try removing that and then see if that gets you closer to a working view.

Like the comments mentioned, you also should **not** be rendering the form twice (once with `form.as_p` and later each field separately)

Comment: i want to remove user registration form from forms.py ... and want to take output from register.html.... then what should i write in form.py so that it goes to my views.py